# Mac mini m1 + VS Code + C Programming = Not Working

Tags: c, macos, visual-studio-code, apple-m1

I am self learning to code in C using Mac mini M1 and VS Code. I get the below error:

Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
"_main", referenced from:
implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Please note:

- Installed the VS Code Insiders for ARM apple version!
- Clang is installed!
- Xcode command line tools installed!
- C/C++ 1.4.0-insiders2 extension is installed in VS Code!
- Code Runner 0.11.4 is installed in VS Code!

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("test");
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled using:
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -o test test.c

Comment: I am confused. Do you get this error when you compile in terminal, or when you try and compile in VSCode?

Comment: in any case. Post the content of `task.json`, `launch.json`, `c_cpp_properties.json` and the result of running in terminal `gcc -v` and `clang -v`

Answer (score -1):

Okay! It's because you forget to save your program before executing i.e you should compile and run. Instead of just running it! #Keeplearning!